# R. ggmap. Overlaying geometric density plot with polygon with different dataset

Tags: r, ggmap

All,

I am fairly new to programming and R, but have spent quite some time on this issue.

I am trying to overlay two maps, based on two different datasets. The first is a density map and the second is a geometric polygon. I can plot the two plots separately but when I plot them together I get the following message: "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale". I tried adding `inherit.aes= FALSE` as I suspected this could be an issue based on earlier posts, but it does not help

```
US_map=get_map(location="united states", zoom=4)
ggmap(US_map, extent="device")+
  geom_polygon(inherit.aes=FALSE, 
data=fortify(coords),aes(x=coords[,1],y=coords[,2], fill="orange", 
colour="black", alpha=1))+
  annotate("text",x=long_average,y=35,label=share_in_frame_perc,size=4)+
geom_density_2d(inherit.aes=FALSE, data=Mill_dots_T,aes(x=Mill_dots_T[,1], 
y=Mill_dots_T[,2]), size=0.3)+
  stat_density2d(data=Mill_dots_T,
             aes(x=Mill_dots_T[,1], y=Mill_dots_T[,2], 
fill=..level..,alpha=..level..), size=0.01, bins=16, geom="polygon")+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(rainbow(7)), breaks=c(0.006, 0.0125, 
0.025, 0.05,0,01,0.02,0.03))+
  scale_alpha(range= c(0.2,1), guide=FALSE)
```

My data looks a little bit like this:

```
Mill_dots_T
long_rect (first column)
-70
-70
-80
-80
-70
...

lat_rect (second column)
35
45
45
35
35
...
```

"Mill_dots_T" data looks like a little bit like this

```
Longitude (first column)
-86,8
-86,8
-86,8
-86,8
-86,3
-86,3
-86,3
-86,3
....
Latitude (second column)
33,5
33,5
33,5
33,5
33,5
32,3
32,3
32,3
32,3
32,3
32,3
32,3
32,3
32,3
....
```

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for info on how to make a reproducible example. That will make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you. Do you see anything that seems odd in the code by simply looking at it? It will probably take me some hours to prepare a reproducible example given my level of expertise...

Comment: My data looks like this